# Transform a data frame with the total count of observations (people) into one with rows for each observation (person)

Tags: r, dataframe, data-conversion

I have a data set like this:

```
    > df<-data.frame(gender=c(rep("male",3),rep("female",3)),
    Age=c(rep("old",3),rep("young",3)),VAR=c(rep(1:3),rep(1:3)),
    FEN1=c(21,26,29,30,6,11),FEN2=c(14,55,12,33,9,21),
    FEN3=c(88,23,55,23,14,66))
```

Where FEN1, FEN2 and FEN3 contain the total number of individuals belonging to that group and which have the characteristics of the columns VAR, Gender, Age, FEN.

And I need to change it to a data frame where each row belongs to one person (536 rows in total) with the characteristics of the columns VAR, Gender, Age.

The expected output would contain:

- 21 rows with information: male, old, 1, FEN1
- 14 rows with information: male, old, 1, FEN2
- 88 rows with information: male, old, 1, FEN3
- 26 rows with information: male, old, 2, FEN1
- 55 rows with information: male, old, 2, FEN2
- 23 rows with information: male, old, 2, FEN3
- and so on...

I was trying to do this by hand with a code like:

```
    > df2<-as.data.frame(1:536)
    > FEN <- c(rep("FEN1",123), rep("FEN2",144), rep("FEN3",269))
    > df2$FEN<-FEN
    > Gender<-c(rep("male",...)...
```

But obviously it is not at all efficient.

Comment: Eventually you can reshape from wide to long http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format and then use the numbers to replicate the rows. Or for each row you are taking the numbers from FEN1, FEN2, FEN3 and constructing new dataframes for later rbind().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method that uses base R methods.

```
# get the vector names that are used to repeat
fenCats <- tail(names(df), 3)
# construct a list of data.frames where the rows have been repeated
# one data.frame for each of the FEN variables
temp <- Map(function(x) df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), x), 1:3], df[fenCats])
# combine list of data.frames and add column with FEN categories
dfNew <- cbind(do.call(rbind, temp),
               "fenCats"=rep(fenCats, colSums(df[fenCats])))
```

we can verify that the row counts are correct with

```
nrow(dfNew) == sum(colSums(df[fenCats])) &
nrow(dfNew) == sum(rowSums(df[fenCats]))
[1] TRUE
```

As an additional verification, we can also perform a quick verification by pulling the first row of each group using subsetting and `cumsum`:

```
dfNew[cumsum(unlist(df[,fenCats])),]
          gender   Age VAR fenCats
FEN1.1.20   male   old   1    FEN1
FEN1.2.25   male   old   2    FEN1
FEN1.3.28   male   old   3    FEN1
FEN1.4.29 female young   1    FEN1
FEN1.5.5  female young   2    FEN1
FEN1.6.10 female young   3    FEN1
FEN2.1.13   male   old   1    FEN2
FEN2.2.54   male   old   2    FEN2
FEN2.3.11   male   old   3    FEN2
FEN2.4.32 female young   1    FEN2
FEN2.5.8  female young   2    FEN2
FEN2.6.20 female young   3    FEN2
FEN3.1.87   male   old   1    FEN3
FEN3.2.22   male   old   2    FEN3
FEN3.3.54   male   old   3    FEN3
FEN3.4.22 female young   1    FEN3
FEN3.5.13 female young   2    FEN3
FEN3.6.65 female young   3    FEN3
```